# Is omitting type="text" on an input considered bad practice?

Tags: html

I have an HTML page that is way too junky, so I am trying to trim it down.

I always put `type='text'` on my inputs, when they are text inputs:

```
<input type="text" />
```

However, it doesn't seem that browsers strictly require that.

Is omitting this attribute where it is text considered bad practice?

Comment: If you are looking at modern browsers, they will surely handel it. But if your users are using older browsers (specially IE-older one) then gods know what will happen. ;)

Comment: the accepted answer is wrong see the answer with the heighest score

Comment: You can remove it but it makes your code harder to understand, the only reason this will be useful is if you need to minify the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer to this question we can refer to:

HTML4 SPEC [17.4 The INPUT element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)

> type =
>   text|password|checkbox|radio|submit|reset|file|hidden|image|button
>   [CI] This attribute specifies the type of control to create. The
>   default value for this attribute is "text".

The HTML5 Spec [4.10.5 The input element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)

> The type attribute controls the data type (and associated control) of
>   the element. It is an enumerated attribute. The missing value default
>   is the Text state.

So, omitting the attribute is not considerable a bad practice

Answer (score 6):

The `type` attribute has always been optional, defaulting to `text`, in all HTML specifications (which start from [HTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.1.2.1)) and in all implementations. It is thus safe to omit it, and of course equally safe to include it, when you want to have a text input field.

In the DOM, `<input>` and `<input type=text>`, have the same representation (including the presence of a `type` property of the element node, with the value `'text'`), except that only in the latter case the `attributes` property contains `type`. So any JavaScript processing that needs the `type` property works just the same.

It is a matter of opinion and taste whether it is useful to include it for symmetry with other `input` elements or for explicitness, so that a person reading HTML source will immediately see that we have a text input field, without needing to scan a possibly long list of attributes to see that no `type` attribute is present.

However, there is a technical difference that may matter, possibly making it advantageous to use the `type=text` attribute. In CSS, the selector `input[type=text]` matches only elements that have the attribute `type=text` explicitly set. If such attributes are used consistently, you can thus set styling properties for text input fields without affecting any other `input` fields. Otherwise you need a more complicated selector.

Answer (score 1):

text is the default value for an input tag's type attribute in most if not all modern browsers. However, it isn't considered a "bad practice" to leave it off, only /good/ practice to include it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at modern browsers, they will surely handle it. But if your users are using older browsers (specially IE-older ones) then gods know what will happen. ;)